# How to compare Time in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following ruby code:

```
session.each do |loads|
    time= session.GetTime
    puts time
end
```

This code returns multiple values:

```
2014-05-04T10:11:24.509-04:00

2014-03-04T11:01:39.242-04:00

2014-06-22T19:47:58.477-04:00

2014-02-21T23:56:25.869-04:00
```

I would like to compare the times and return only values greater than `2014-06-01`. I get conversion errors if I just use `>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have not given enough information in your question and you've omitted the most important line of code for your question - which is the comparative operation itself. At a glance, the only assumption we can make at this stage is that your not actually comparing dates like you think you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_time = Time.new(2014, 06, 01)
```

then try

```
time >= my_time
```

Answer (score 1):

`Time.strptime` is the workhorse method for parsing Time values:

```
require 'time'

TIME_SPLIT = Time.parse('2014-06-01')

times = %w[
  2014-05-04T10:11:24.509-04:00
  2014-03-04T11:01:39.242-04:00
  2014-06-22T19:47:58.477-04:00
  2014-02-21T23:56:25.869-04:00
].select{ |t| Time.strptime(t, '%FT%T.%L%z') > TIME_SPLIT }
# => ["2014-06-22T19:47:58.477-04:00"]
```

`Time.parse` is also useful, but it can be fooled by values that look like a MM/DD/YYYY form but are actually DD/MM/YYYY, where the date is greater than 12. Dates in the US are typically MM/DD/YYYY so people get confused when something like '12/31/2000' fails:

```
Time.parse('12/31/2000')
ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

The problem is, there is no month "31", it's a day.

```
Time.parse('31/12/2000')
# => 2000-12-31 00:00:00 -0700
```

Similarly, some dates could be nebulous and, as a result, be parsed incorrectly. If this date is from a US customer the month would be assumed to be first, but from another region it'd be the date:

```
Time.parse('01/02/2000') # => 2000-02-01 00:00:00 -0700
```

but, again, parse thought it was a day, so watch out.

Instead of letting `parse` try and possibly get it wrong or fail, it's better to define the formats your code can understand, look at the region the data comes from, then apply the appropriate format. These are two different ways of saying the same thing:

```
Time.strptime('2014-05-04T10:11:24.509-04:00', '%FT%T.%L%z') # => 2014-05-04 07:11:24 -0700
Time.strptime('2014-03-04T11:01:39.242-04:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z') # => 2014-03-04 08:01:39 -0700
```

And how to define whether the month is first or second:

```
Time.strptime('01/02/2001', '%m/%d/%Y') # => 2001-01-02 00:00:00 -0700
Time.strptime('01/02/2001', '%d/%m/%Y') # => 2001-02-01 00:00:00 -0700
```

You can find out more about `strptime` and the format strings in [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-strptime).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Time.parse()` on your `time` objects, it should convert them to more Ruby-friendly objects and allow you to compare them using `>` and `<=`, etc.